# Page animation with gatsby, transition-link and gsap

Tags: javascript, transition, gatsby, gsap

I'm new to gatsbyjs and i'm trying to do a custom page animation.

I found a plugin name transition-link with gatsby => [Plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-transition-link/)

Basically what I want to do is a custom swipe animation like this one : [demo-site](https://gatsby-plugin-transition-link.netlify.com/) when you "Go to page 2 that way  and animate in the next page". Custom because I want it to come from the top right corner to take the whole page when open and when close the same effect but revert.

I really don't know if I'm in the good direction (not really use to js and even more to animation but right now I have the following code) :

```
function animationClose(node, e,exit,entry){
        if(window !=="undefined") {
            var w = window.innerWidth; 
            var h = window.innerHeight;}
        var tl = new TimelineLite(); 
        tl.from(node,1,{x:-w,y:h}).to(node,1,{ x: 0,y:0});
    }     
<TransitionLink 
                to={link}
                exit={{

                  }}
                entry={{
                    trigger: ({ node, e, exit, entry }) => animationClose(node),
                  }}
                >
                <img src={logoClose} id="closeMenu" alt="fermeture du menu"/>
     </TransitionLink>
```

So my node trigger by my entry fonction do the good movement but my background is white. I want to have as my background my node trigger by exit but i can't find a way to have it visible while the animation trigger during the entry is happening.

Thank's in advance!

Comment: I understand most of your question but I do not understand this sentence: "I want to have as my background my node trigger by exit but i can't find a way to have it visible while the animation trigger during the entry is happening." Can you please try re-explaining what you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry! Well, I have my two pages, one is the node in entry and the other one is the node in exit.  I want the page I'm leaving from to stay in background while the other is "comming". My other goal is to make the reverse effect (the comming page is in the background while the other one is exiting the window with the effect that I mention in my post).

Comment: Does the Gatsby plugin allow for that? You'd need to have both pages loaded before the exit animation starts in order for them to be layered.

Comment: Alternatively you could have just a solid colored background that comes in over top of the old content and then fade in the new content once it's loaded. That's much more doable.

Comment: Do you know any plugin that could do that? Yeah, I already think about that and I guess I will do this for now but it would be great if I figure out a way to achieve my goal! Thank's for your answer anyway

Comment: You might be able to do it in Gatsby, I've never used it. Barba [can do it](https://github.com/barbajs/barba/issues/256) I think. Maybe a similar approach would work in Gatsby?